# iMacros - Random String of Numbers

Tags: string, random, numbers, imacros

In iMacros I want it to generate a random string of 6 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET rnd EVAL("('' + Math.random()).substr(2, 6)")
'PROMPT {{rnd}}
```

Answer (score 0):

SET rnd EVAL("Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 6)")

PROMPT {{rnd}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
SET RANDOM_NUMBER EVAL("Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000) + 100000;")
PROMPT {{RANDOM_NUMBER}}
```

Hope it helps.